# How to structure an api when you have different permissions

Tags: api, rest, api-design

Currently my api was built for user management and various things they can do in the system

currently I have a users endpoint and locations endpoint:

```
LIST - GET - users
CREATE - POST - users/{id}
UPDATE - PUT - users/{id}
DELETE - DELETE - users/{id}

LIST - GET - locations
CREATE - POST - locations/{id}
UPDATE - PUT - locations/{id}
DELETE - DELETE - locations/{id}
```

Now that's great I can manage all my users and locations.. but now somewhere else in my application a user only has access to see some of those users, or some locations due to their permissions, managing users is really an admin thing. Would I need another endpoint for this?

How would someone go about conveying this in an api? Maybe one of the following?

```
GET /current/users
GET /current/locations

GET users/mine
GET locations/mine

GET/users?mine=true
GET/locations?mine=true
```

I can't seem to find any good information on this. Very much appreciated!

Comment: read this https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: @fuzzybear I just read that whole thing before posting and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: rest is rarley used exactly like the textbook, in your scenario if it's permissions depends what kind, you could look them up in a where clause and add a method to you existing API controller or as you say create a new controller, there is no exact best practice as not all scenarios fit within the spec, personally I go with a less cluttered approach so normally i'd create a new controller, but if it's just one method I may just add to an existing controller. hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first way, my team also use this way (current/me) to get some information of current user.

As Facebook also use **/me**/... endpoints to retrieve the information of current user.

```
GET /current/users
GET /current/locations
```

The benefices of this way, we can create new controller to manage current user information and reuse other service/endpoint to retrieve data. We don't need to interfere userController or locationController ...